# Send message to a group of users in SignalR Service in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr-service

Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service.md) for the SignalR bindings to send a message to a specified user you include the `UserId` property on the message as such -

```cs
[FunctionName("SendMessage")]
public static Task SendMessage(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]object message, 
    [SignalR(HubName = "chat")]IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages)
{
    return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
        new SignalRMessage 
        {
            // the message will only be sent to these user IDs
            UserId = "userId1",
            Target = "newMessage", 
            Arguments = new [] { message } 
        });
}
```

This example is taken straight from the documentation, but the comment implies you message *multiple* userids, even though the property is a string and not an array.

How would you specify multiple users? (If for example, they are in a private chat channel together) Or is this mistake in the wording of the comment and you would need to send a message per user?

With other versions of SignalR I would put them in a group, but bindings for this do not exist for functions.

Comment: You mean this text, which says connections? 
"You can send a message only to connections that have been authenticated to a user by setting the UserId property of the SignalR message."

Comment: @anthony-chu Would you be able to share your insights on this? Thanks.

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT with other SignalR libraries it's possible to add authenticated users to a distribution group, then call signalr with the group name and it will handle broadcasting to all those clients for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately just like the doc says, right now with Azure function binding we can only send message to one user or to all clients.

See [the code of current extension SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/blob/v1.0.0-preview1-10002/src/SignalRServiceExtension/Client/IAzureSignalRSender.cs) `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService` v1.0.0-preview1-10002. 
It shows the extension has only two methods SendToAll and SendToUser.

```
    Task SendToAll(string hubName, SignalRData data);
    Task SendToUser(string hubName, string userId, SignalRData data);
```

The comment confused you is actually for [old sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/e28c02f89af5f312381aad7a7eda41f6eb153abc#diff-9eaadde8b7a95754c6d26fb2bf6674c0), the author forgot to modify it.

Good news is that support for group operation is [under progress](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/pull/33).

Answer (score 3):

Group operations were introduced in the [latest release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/releases/tag/v1.0.0-preview1-10025).

Now you can:

- Send a message to a group using `GroupName` in `SignalRMessage`
- Add/remove user in a group using `IAsyncCollector<SignalRGroupAction>` output